Help please to remove "Ctrl", "Alt", "Shift" icons poping up near coursor in Adobe Illustrator (Windows10 + Wacom)
Recently, after updating Windows 10 (64 bit), in Adobe Illustrator, near the cursor, the very annoying icons "Ctrl," "Alt," and "Shift" began to appear when pressing the corresponding buttons. Also, the Wacom pen pressure mode disappeared.
In the beginning, everything works fine, and this bug appears after a few minutes of work. But if you switch Alt+Tab to another program and then return to Adobe Illustrator, this bug disappears for a few minutes but then appears again – icons "Ctrl," "Alt," and "Shift" appear again, and brush pressure disappears.


Hi. This has nothing to do with Illustrator. It's a Windows 10 issue. See this link on the Microsoft Answers site. Also if your wacom tablet has stopped working, you may need to update the drivers.

Thank you, Billy. I'll check it out.
Yes, I realize it's Windows, not Illustrator; I think it's time to disallow auto-update.
Wacom is working fine with the last driver. It worked fine before the next Windows update...
